# How to merge entries from two TINIfile instances?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, ini

Is there a way to merge entries from one TIniFile instance to another?

Comment: Not directly, no.  You have to read values from one `TIniFile` and write them to the other `TIniFile` as needed.  If you are having trouble doing that, please show your actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a procedure which can merge two INI files together into a new output INI  file:

```
procedure MergeIniFiles(const FromFilename, ToFilename, OutputFilename: String;
  const Overwrite: Boolean);
var
  IniFrom, IniTo, IniOut: TIniFile;
  Sec: TStringList;
  Val: TStringList;
  X, Y: Integer;
  S, N, V: String;
begin
  IniFrom:= TIniFile.Create(FromFilename);
  IniTo:= TIniFile.Create(ToFilename);
  IniOut:= TIniFile.Create(OutputFilename);
  Sec:= TStringList.Create;
  Val:= TStringList.Create;
  try
    IniFrom.ReadSections(Sec);
    for X := 0 to Sec.Count-1 do begin
      S:= Sec[X];
      IniFrom.ReadSection(S, Val);
      for Y := 0 to Val.Count-1 do begin
        N:= Val[Y];
        V:= IniFrom.ReadString(S, N, '');
        IniOut.WriteString(S, N, V);
      end;
    end;

    IniTo.ReadSections(Sec);
    for X := 0 to Sec.Count-1 do begin
      S:= Sec[X];
      IniTo.ReadSection(S, Val);
      for Y := 0 to Val.Count-1 do begin
        N:= Val[Y];
        V:= IniTo.ReadString(S, N, '');
        if Overwrite then begin
          IniOut.WriteString(S, N, V);
        end else begin
          if not IniOut.ValueExists(S, N) then
            IniOut.WriteString(S, N, V);
        end;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    Val.Free;
    Sec.Free;
    IniOut.Free;
    IniTo.Free;
    IniFrom.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for the implementation, I'll have to alter to work with TINIFile parameters.

Comment: @VassilisGr Indeed, I was only guessing what the intentions were. It's up to you to decide how to accommodate for existing values.

Answer (score 4):

There's no single method to do so. You can do it yourself like this:

1. Load the INI file, let's call them A and B.
2. Enumerate the sections in B.
3. For each section in B, enumerate the name/value pairs in that section.
4. Add each name/value pair from B into the corresponding section in A.
5. When complete, save file A, which contains the entries from both files.

The methods that you'll use to enumerate file A are `ReadSections` and `ReadSectionValues`.

You'll need to decide what to do about any clashes. That is any names that appear in both files.

Comment: "You'll need to decide " Indeed, + 1

Comment: `ReadSectionValues` +1. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What I wanted to achieve is to have an ini file in my setup program, which would be placed along with the main executable in the 'Program Files'. This ini will contain the default values for many properties of the application. So the user's actual ini file (ex. in home folder) will read the "factory" defaults from there. This approach is something like OSX's `NSUserDefaults`. I think that in *some cases* this is useful instead of just using the default value in `inifile.readString()`. Thank you all for your answers, I just post the final functions for this purpose...

```
procedure inifileLoadDefaults(const defaults: TFileName; destination:TIniFile);
var inif: TIniFile;
begin
    inif := TIniFile.Create(defaults);
    try
        inifileLoadDefaults(inif, destination);
    finally
        inif.Free;
    end;
end;


procedure inifileLoadDefaults(const defaults: TIniFile; destination:TIniFile);
var secs, secsVal: TStrings;
    i, k: Integer;
begin
    secs := TStringList.Create;
    secsVal := TStringList.Create;
    try
        defaults.ReadSections(secs);
        for i:=0 to secs.Count -1 do begin
            defaults.ReadSection(secs[i], secsVal);
            for k:=0 to secsVal.Count -1 do
                if not(destination.ValueExists(secs[i], secsVal[k])) then
                    destination.WriteString(secs[i], secsVal[k], defaults.ReadString(secs[i], secsVal[k], ''));
        end;

    finally
        secsVal.Free;
        secs.Free;
    end;
end;
```